# How to use redux persist to support offline?

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

I have a react native mobile application and I need some pages to work offline (without internet connection) I am using redux persist library.

My question is where to initialize the store and persist it?

Should I make it for each page or one time?

Answer (score 0):

You use it to persist either your entire redux store, or a part of the store. If your not using redux yet then you will need to implement that first.

It’s setup at the same time you create your redux store.

There are links to several examples and a guide start guide in the [GitHub project readme](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/README.md).